# Gatsby site isn't rendering gifs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, gatsby, gif

### Summary

Hello, I come asking for help – I've spent two whole days now trying to figure it out now.
I can't seem to crack how to get gifs to load on my site. (I'm pretty new to coding so forgive me if this something obvious)

js location: src/page/volvic

**bring them in like so:**
import volvic from "../../content/assets/projects/volic.gif"

**and call it like so:**
`<img src={volvic} />`

**gives me this error:**
*(terminal)*

```
ERROR #98123 WEBPAC
Generating development JavaScript bundle failed
Unexpected character '' (1:6)
File: content/assets/projects/volvic.gif:1:6
```

–––––
*(localhost)*

`./content/assets/projects/volvic.gif 1:6Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:6)You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders(Source code omitted for this binary file)`

Can someone point me the right direction please, any help would be greatly appreciated.

#### Environment (if relevant)

https://github.com/supnim/new-port - repo

```
    OS: macOS 10.16
    CPU: (16) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9880H CPU @ 2.30GHz
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.4.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
    npm: 6.14.5 - /usr/local/bin/npm
  Languages:
    Python: 2.7.16 - /usr/bin/python
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 81.0.4044.138
    Safari: 14.0
  npmPackages:
    gatsby: ^2.23.4 => 2.23.4
    gatsby-image: ^2.4.12 => 2.4.12
    gatsby-plugin-feed: ^2.5.5 => 2.5.5
    gatsby-plugin-google-analytics: ^2.3.4 => 2.3.4
    gatsby-plugin-manifest: ^2.4.11 => 2.4.11
    gatsby-plugin-netlify: ^2.3.5 => 2.3.5
    gatsby-plugin-offline: ^2.1.0 => 2.2.10
    gatsby-plugin-postcss: ^2.3.4 => 2.3.4
    gatsby-plugin-purgecss: ^3.1.1 => 3.1.1
    gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^3.3.4 => 3.3.4
    gatsby-plugin-react-svg: ^3.0.0 => 3.0.0
    gatsby-plugin-sass: ^2.3.4 => 2.3.4
    gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^2.6.17 => 2.6.17
    gatsby-plugin-smoothscroll: ^1.1.0 => 1.1.0
    gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader: ^1.0.4 => 1.0.4
    gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files: ^2.3.10 => 2.3.10
    gatsby-remark-embed-video: ^2.0.1 => 2.0.1
    gatsby-remark-images: ^2.0.6 => 2.0.6
    gatsby-remark-prismjs: ^3.5.4 => 3.5.4
    gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe: ^2.4.5 => 2.4.5
    gatsby-remark-smartypants: ^2.3.4 => 2.3.4
    gatsby-source-filesystem: ^2.3.11 => 2.3.11
    gatsby-transformer-remark: ^2.8.16 => 2.8.16
    gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^2.5.10 => 2.5.10
  npmGlobalPackages:
    gatsby-cli: 2.12.58
```

#### File contents (if changed)

**gatsby-config.js:**

> ```
> const siteConfig = require("./siteConfig");
>
> //ive just added this
> module.exports = {
>   module: {
>     rules: [
>       {
>         test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
>         use: [
>           "file-loader",
>           {
>             loader: "image-webpack-loader",
>             options: {
>               bypassOnDebug: true, // webpack@1.x
>               disable: true // webpack@2.x and newer
>             }
>           }
>         ]
>       }
>     ]
>   }
> };
> module.exports = {
>   siteMetadata: {
>     title: siteConfig.name,
>     author: siteConfig.author,
>     description: siteConfig.description,
>     siteUrl: urljoin(siteConfig.url, siteConfig.prefix),
>     social: {
>       twitter: siteConfig.twitter
>     }
>   },
>
>   plugins: [
>     {
>       resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
>       options: {
>         path: `${__dirname}/content/blog`,
>         name: `blog`
>       }
>     },
>     {
>       resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
>       options: {
>         path: `${__dirname}/content/assets`,
>         name: `assets`
>       }
>     },
>     {
>       resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
>       options: {
>         path: `${__dirname}/content/assets/photography`,
>         name: `photography`
>       }
>     },
>     {
>       resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
>       options: {
>         path: `${__dirname}/content/assets/heros`,
>         name: `heros`
>       }
>     },
>     {
>       resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
>       options: {
>         plugins: [
>           {
>             resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
>             options: {
>               maxWidth: 1360,
>               withWebp: true,
>               showCaptions: true,
>               quality: 75,
>               wrapperStyle: `margin: 7vw 0;`
>             }
>           },
>           {
>             resolve: "gatsby-remark-embed-video",
>             options: {
>               width: 800,
>               height: 450,
>               related: false,
>               noIframeBorder: true,
>               allowfullscreen: true
>             }
>           },
>
>           {
>             resolve: `gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe`,
>             options: {
>               wrapperStyle: `margin-bottom: 1.0725rem`
>             }
>           },
>           {
>             resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
>             options: {
>               plugins: [`gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe`]
>             }
>           },
>           `gatsby-remark-prismjs`,
>           `gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files`,
>           `gatsby-remark-smartypants`
>         ]
>       }
>     },
>     `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
>     `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
>     `gatsby-remark-embed-video`,
>     `gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe`,
>     {
>       resolve: `gatsby-plugin-postcss`,
>       options: {
>         postCssPlugins: [
>           require("postcss-easy-import")(),
>           require("postcss-custom-properties")({ preserve: false }),
>           require("postcss-color-function")(),
>           require("autoprefixer")({ browsers: ["last 2 versions"] })
>         ]
>       }
>     },
>     {
>       resolve: `gatsby-plugin-purgecss`,
>       options: {
>         printRejected: true // Print removed selectors and processed file names
>         // develop: true, // Enable while using `gatsby develop`
>         // tailwind: true, // Enable tailwindcss support
>         // whitelist: ['whitelist'], // Don't remove this selector
>         // ignore: ['/ignored.css', 'prismjs/', 'docsearch.js/'], // Ignore files/folders
>         // purgeOnly : ['components/', '/main.css', 'bootstrap/'], // Purge only these files/folders
>       }
>     },
>     {
>       resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`,
>       options: {
>         trackingId: `-`
>       }
>     },
>     `gatsby-plugin-feed`,
>     {
>       resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
>       options: {
>         name: siteConfig.name,
>         short_name: siteConfig.shortName,
>         start_url: siteConfig.prefix,
>         background_color: `#ffffff`,
>         theme_color: `#663399`,
>         display: `minimal-ui`,
>         icon: `content/assets/sup.png`
>       }
>     },
>     {
>       resolve: "gatsby-plugin-react-svg",
>       options: {
>         rule: {
>           include: /assets/ // See below to configure properly
>         }
>       }
>     },
>     `gatsby-plugin-netlify`,
>     `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
>     `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
>     `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
>     `gatsby-plugin-smoothscroll`
>   ]
> };
> ```

**`package.json:`**

> ````
>   "name": "supnim.com",
>   "private": true,
>   "description": "Product designer based in London",
>   "version": "1.0.0",
>   "author": "Nimesh Reghunandanan <hello@supnim.com>",
>   "bugs": {
>     "url": "https://github.com/ImedAdel/gatsby-london/issues"
>   },
>   "dependencies": {
>     "acorn": "^7.3.1",
>     "acorn-dynamic-import": "^4.0.0",
>     "core-js": "^3.6.5",
>     "framer": "^1.2.3",
>     "framer-motion": "^1.11.1",
>     "gatsby": "^2.23.4",
>     "gatsby-image": "^2.4.12",
>     "gatsby-plugin-feed": "^2.5.5",
>     "gatsby-plugin-google-analytics": "^2.3.4",
>     "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.4.11",
>     "gatsby-plugin-netlify": "^2.3.5",
>     "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^2.1.0",
>     "gatsby-plugin-postcss": "^2.3.4",
>     "gatsby-plugin-purgecss": "^3.1.1",
>     "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.3.4",
>     "gatsby-plugin-react-svg": "^3.0.0",
>     "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.3.4",
>     "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.6.17",
>     "gatsby-plugin-smoothscroll": "^1.1.0",
>     "gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader": "^1.0.4",
>     "gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files": "^2.3.10",
>     "gatsby-remark-embed-video": "^2.0.1",
>     "gatsby-remark-images": "^2.0.6",
>     "gatsby-remark-prismjs": "^3.5.4",
>     "gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe": "^2.4.5",
>     "gatsby-remark-smartypants": "^2.3.4",
>     "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.3.11",
>     "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^2.8.16",
>     "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.5.10",
>     "jshint": "^2.11.1",
>     "motion": "^5.0.0-beta26",
>     "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
>     "open": "^7.0.4",
>     "path": "^0.12.7",
>     "prismjs": "^1.20.0",
>     "react": "^16.13.1",
>     "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
>     "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
>     "react-icons": "^3.10.0",
>     "react-images": "^1.1.7",
>     "react-photo-gallery": "^8.0.0",
>     "react-refresh": "^0.8.3",
>     "sharp": "^0.25.4",
>     "stream": "0.0.2",
>     "tsutils": "^3.17.1",
>     "typescript": "^3.9.5",
>     "url-join": "^4.0.0",
>     "url-loader": "^4.1.0"
>   },
>   "devDependencies": {
>     "autoprefixer": "^9.8.4",
>     "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
>     "husky": "^2.2.0",
>     "image-webpack-loader": "^6.0.0",
>     "postcss-color-function": "^4.1.0",
>     "postcss-custom-properties": "^8.0.10",
>     "postcss-easy-import": "^3.0.0",
>     "prettier": "^1.19.1",
>     "pretty-quick": "^1.10.0"
>   },
>   "homepage": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-blog#readme",
>   "keywords": [
>     "gatsby",
>     "ghost",
>     "gallery",
>     "blog",
>     "starter"
>   ],
>   "license": "MIT",
>   "main": "n/a",
>   "repository": {
>     "type": "git",
>     "url": "git+https://github.com/ImedAdel/gatsby-london.git"
>   },
>   "scripts": {
>     "build": "gatsby build",
>     "develop": "gatsby develop",
>     "format": "prettier --write src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
>     "start": "npm run develop",
>     "serve": "gatsby serve",
>     "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\""
>   },
>   "husky": {
>     "hooks": {
>       "pre-commit": "pretty-quick --staged"
>     }
>   }
> }```
> ````

Once again any help would be highly appreciated :)

Comment: Is there a reason, you want to use the package `image-webpack-loader` vs default functionality on loading gifs ? https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/working-with-gifs/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do any extra loader to load a `.gif` file. It's exactly the same than render any image. You just need to import the component and use that as an image source.

I would suggest removing that configuration in your `gatsby-config.js` (the whole first `module.exports`) because if you want to add any webpack loader, that's not the place, you'll need to create it in `gatsby-node.js` file and using [Gatsby's API for custom configuration](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-custom-webpack-config/) (`onCreateWebpackConfig`, etc). It's advanced stuff and I don't think that it's what you need right now.

According to [Gatsby's docs about `.gifs` files](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/working-with-gifs/):

> In Markdown posts and pages, including an animated GIF is the same as
> a static image:

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/templates/Layout/Layout';
import test from '../assets/test.gif';

const Index = props => {
  return <Layout>
    <h1>Hi people</h1>
    <img src={test}/>
  </Layout>;
};
```

And as I said, your `gatsby-config.js` should look like:

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: siteConfig.name,
    author: siteConfig.author,
    description: siteConfig.description,
    siteUrl: urljoin(siteConfig.url, siteConfig.prefix),
    social: {
      twitter: siteConfig.twitter
    }
  },

  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/content/blog`,
        name: `blog`
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/content/assets`,
        name: `assets`
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/content/assets/photography`,
        name: `photography`
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/content/assets/heros`,
        name: `heros`
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
      options: {
        plugins: [
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-images`,
            options: {
              maxWidth: 1360,
              withWebp: true,
              showCaptions: true,
              quality: 75,
              wrapperStyle: `margin: 7vw 0;`
            }
          },
          {
            resolve: "gatsby-remark-embed-video",
            options: {
              width: 800,
              height: 450,
              related: false,
              noIframeBorder: true,
              allowfullscreen: true
            }
          },

          {
            resolve: `gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe`,
            options: {
              wrapperStyle: `margin-bottom: 1.0725rem`
            }
          },
          {
            resolve: `gatsby-transformer-remark`,
            options: {
              plugins: [`gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe`]
            }
          },
          `gatsby-remark-prismjs`,
          `gatsby-remark-copy-linked-files`,
          `gatsby-remark-smartypants`
        ]
      }
    },
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-remark-embed-video`,
    `gatsby-remark-responsive-iframe`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-postcss`,
      options: {
        postCssPlugins: [
          require("postcss-easy-import")(),
          require("postcss-custom-properties")({ preserve: false }),
          require("postcss-color-function")(),
          require("autoprefixer")({ browsers: ["last 2 versions"] })
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-purgecss`,
      options: {
        printRejected: true // Print removed selectors and processed file names
        // develop: true, // Enable while using `gatsby develop`
        // tailwind: true, // Enable tailwindcss support
        // whitelist: ['whitelist'], // Don't remove this selector
        // ignore: ['/ignored.css', 'prismjs/', 'docsearch.js/'], // Ignore files/folders
        // purgeOnly : ['components/', '/main.css', 'bootstrap/'], // Purge only these files/folders
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-analytics`,
      options: {
        trackingId: `-`
      }
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-feed`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: siteConfig.name,
        short_name: siteConfig.shortName,
        start_url: siteConfig.prefix,
        background_color: `#ffffff`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `content/assets/sup.png`
      }
    },
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-react-svg",
      options: {
        rule: {
          include: /assets/ // See below to configure properly
        }
      }
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-netlify`,
    `gatsby-plugin-offline`,
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    `gatsby-plugin-smoothscroll`
  ]
};
```

I've just checked it out in my local machine and works.

If you need to add extra controls, you may need to check out some external libraries such as [react-gif-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gif-player).

Comment: thanks for replying, but the problem seemed to be: gatsby-plugin-react-svg, once I moved my .gif to components it worked. thanks anyways. p.s you're totally right about removing the first part of config :)

Comment: Indeed, that's what I was suggesting. I'm glad it helped.